# IIS7 as site title

Tags: iis7

When I search for my website on google both the title and description are showing as IIS7, how can I change this to a proper description?

Comment: Show us some code ...

Comment: What are you searching for? Google will modify the title and description that appears in the SERPs by what the user is searching for.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already done so, you need title and description tags in the head.

Like this:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>This will be your site title (up to 60 characters)</TITLE>
<META Name="Description" Content="This is the description of your site (up to 200 characters)." >
</HEAD>
```